# JavaScript code do not works on online server

Tags: jquery, javascript, child-theme, wp-enqueue-script

I am using a jQuery Image Zoom plugin (http://jacklmoore.com/zoom/) in my wordpress website.

The matter is that it works fine in my local machine, but on online server don't work. The JavaScript console of Firebug (Firefox) and on Chrome don't launch any error.

Curiously, the other scripts works perfectly, on local machine and on online server.

What have I missing?

This is how I am including the files in child theme:

`functions.php`

```
function x_theme_enqueue_scripts() {
    wp_enqueue_script( 'jquery' );
    wp_enqueue_script( 'jquery-zoom-scripts',  get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/framework/js/dist/site/jquery.zoom.min.js', array( 'jquery' ), '1.0.0', true );
    wp_enqueue_script( 'swipe-scripts',  get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/framework/js/dist/site/jquery.touchSwipe.min.js', false );
    wp_enqueue_script( 'custom-scripts',  get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/framework/js/dist/site/custom-scripts.js', false );
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'x_theme_enqueue_scripts' );
```

`custom-script.js`

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
    initSwipe();
});

jQuery(window).load(function($) {
    zoomProductImages();
});

function zoomProductImages(){
    jQuery(function ($) { 

        $("#sh-images-main").zoom();

        $('.sh-images-gallery').find('.product-image-item img').on('click', function(){
            $("#sh-product-main-image").attr('src', $(this).attr('src'));
            $("#sh-product-main-image").data('zoom-image', $(this).attr('src'));
            $("#sh-images-main").zoom({
                url: $(this).attr('src')
            });
            // $('#sh-images-main .zoomImg').attr('src', $(this).attr('src'));
        });
    }); 
}
```

**EDIT:**

For some strangerous reason, the script is loading only some times, the javascript console is not launching anything still.

I believe if i use a way to launch the `zoomProductImages()` function only when all interested images load, I will avoid this issue.

What do you think?

Comment: Can you confirm if the javascript file is being enqueued?

Comment: Yes, it is being loaded!